# Is it norml for smoke to come out of exhaust?

Tags: car, exhaust

Hi got out of my car while the engine was still running and noticed smoke kept leaving the exhaust.  I wondered of this was normal as I dont see this site with most cars.

I also noticed a vacuum sounding smell coming from the car while this was happening.  Note this may have been the fan/heating which I may have left on but cant remember so it may have been something else.

Is there anything that maybe wrong with the car especially considering the ongoing smoke the exhaust was emitting.

Comment: What color is the smoke? (Be specific, as it could be light white or heavy white, blue, or black ... it's important).  Also, what do you mean by a "vacuum sounding smell"? You seem to be mixing terms here.

Comment: First off, what kind of car do you have? Electric cars, for example, shouldn't have an exhaust or an exhaust smell. Diesel cars may have more of a smell than cars that burn gas. You should, however, expect exhaust to come out of the exhaust pipe.

Comment: What is a "vacuum sounding smell"? I've never heard, smelled or seen a vacuum (it being the absence of. .well.. everything)

Comment: lol did I write that? looks like I did.  I probably meant vacuum sound which I came to realise is the fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the white fumes is "normally" water vapour condensing, the engine will produce exhaust gas when it is running.